# How to pass a captured image from custom camera to another activity?

Tags: java, android, image, camera, imageview

I'm presently trying to build a custom camera application that will capture an image and then display it in another activity (by updating the ImageView).

At the moment I can successfully capture and save an image on the device through my camera preview, and can even successfully update an ImageView within that activity with the captured image - however, I'm having a lot more difficulty in passing the captured image to the second activity.

I see a lot of solutions online using a combination of ActivityResult and Intent, but they all seem to use the device's native camera app and not by using a custom camera like mine is.

My CameraActivity class looks like this:

```
@SuppressLint("ClickableViewAccessibility")
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.camera_activity);
    swatch = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.swatch);
    preview = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.camera_preview);
    cameraButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.captureButton);


    cameraButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            mCamera.takePicture(null, null, mPicture);

        }
    });
}

private Camera.PictureCallback mPicture = new Camera.PictureCallback() {

    @Override
    public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {

        File pictureFile = getOutputMediaFile(MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE);
        if (pictureFile == null) {
            Log.d("Camera error",
                    "Error creating media file, check storage permissions: ");
            return;
        }
        Log.i("Picture", pictureFile.toString());
        try {

            final ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(pictureFile);
            fos.write(data);
            fos.close();
            BitmapFactory.Options scalingOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            scalingOptions.inSampleSize = camera.getParameters().getPictureSize().width / imageView.getMeasuredWidth();
            final Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length, scalingOptions);

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            Log.d("Camera error", "File not found: " + e.getMessage());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.d("Camera error", "Error accessing file: " + e.getMessage());
        }

        finish();
        openColourDetectorActivity();
    }
};

private static File getOutputMediaFile(int type) {

    File mediaStorageDir = new File(
            Environment
                    .getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM),
            "Medici");
    if (!mediaStorageDir.exists()) {
        if (!mediaStorageDir.mkdirs()) {
            Log.i("Medici", "failed to create directory");
            return null;
        }
    }

    @SuppressLint("SimpleDateFormat") String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyymmddhhmmss")
            .format(new Date());
    File mediaFile;
    if (type == MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE) {
        mediaFile = new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator
                + "IMG_" + timeStamp + ".jpg");
    } else {
        return null;
    }

    return mediaFile;
}


public void openColourDetectorActivity() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, ColourDetectorActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

And of course, I'm trying to receive it on the other end in that activity's onCreate method.

Any idea how I could go about this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
openColourDetectorActivity(pictureFile);

public void openColourDetectorActivity(File file) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, ColourDetectorActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("FILE", file.getPath());
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

in ColourDetectorActivity :

```
new File(getIntent().getStringExtra("FILE"))
```

Comment: Brilliant! That works beautifully. I've gone and converted that File on the second activity to a Bitmap, and used that to update the ImageView and display the photo. So all is working as intended. Thank you very much.